# Optimize Time/Space Complexity for Solving Palindromes

Tags: python, performance, optimization

This problem was recently asked by Twitter:

> A palindrome is a sequence of characters that reads the same backwards and forwards. Given a string, s, find the longest palindromic substring in s.

Example:

```
Input: "banana"
Output: "anana"

Input: "million"
Output: "illi"
```

```
class Solution: 
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
      # Fill this in.
        
# Test program
s = "tracecars"
print(str(Solution().longestPalindrome(s)))
# racecar
```

So i solved it like that

```
class Solution: 
    def longestPalindrome(self, s):
        index = 0
        longestPalindrome = ""
        for x  in s:
            subStr = s[index + 1:]
            nextIndex = subStr.find(x)
            while nextIndex != -1:
                txt = x + subStr
                pland = txt[:nextIndex + 2]
                if self.isPalindromicSubString(pland):
                    if len(pland) > len(longestPalindrome):
                        longestPalindrome = pland
                nextIndex = subStr.find(x,nextIndex + 1)
            index = index + 1
        return longestPalindrome

    def isPalindromicSubString(self,subStr):
        index = 0
        reverseIndex = -1
        isItPalindromic = True
        for y in subStr:
            if y != subStr[reverseIndex]:
               isItPalindromic = False
            index = index + 1
            reverseIndex = reverseIndex - 1  
        return isItPalindromic

# Test program
s = "abcdef aka"
print(str(Solution().longestPalindrome(s)))
# racecar
```

it's works fine and it's time complexity is O(N^2)
is there any way to do it better , and give me your comments about both time,space complexity

Comment: this is a fairly well-known problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring

Comment: In the end, it seems like even the well-known solutions are still ultimately O(N^2)

Comment: @h0r53 From the wikipedia article: >[Manacher's algorithm] provides a linear time solution to the longest palindromic substring problem

Comment: thanks , i just know it fairly well-known problem,
I already solve it , but i want to know if it's can solve with better solution

Comment: @h0r53 actually it's contain while loop inside for loop so it might be o(n^2) alog

Comment: Linear time was for finding a list of palindromes within a string, not the longest palindrome substring

Comment: @Superior updated you can check it now

Comment: small issue in 
```
for x  in s[0:len(s)/2]:
```

chanaged to 

```
for x  in s:
```

Comment: Note that this part is quadratic-time all by itself: `for s in x: {subStr = s[index + 1:]; index += 1}`. Slicing is _not_ `O(1)` in Python.

Comment: @h0r53 if you find the list of palindrome substrings in linear time, you can very easily just keep the maximium with the same time complexity

Answer (score 2):

Here is a python implementation of Manacher's Algorithm, from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring) linked by Kevin

```py
def longest_palindrome_substring(s: str) -> str:
    # Add sentinel chars between chars of s and around s, to handle even length palindromes
    # Different outer chars to exit palindrome expanding loop without boundary checking
    # in case the entire string is a palindrome
    with_boundaries = "@|" + "|".join(s) + "|!"

    # Length of palindrome centered at each index in the new string
    palindrome_lengths = [0 for _ in with_boundaries]

    # Center of current palindrome
    center_current = 0
    # Right boundary of current palindrome
    right_current = 0

    # Track largest palindrome length and center index
    max_len = 0
    max_center = 0
    for i in range(2, len(with_boundaries) - 2):
        # If i is inside a bigger palindrome, copy the length of the mirror palindrome
        # e.g. *abacaba*
        #            ^  the second aba inside abacaba must have the same length of the first
        if i < right_current:
            center_mirror = 2 * center_current - i
            # add only the length of the mirror palindrome inside the current one
            palindrome_lengths[i] = min(right_current - i, palindrome_lengths[center_mirror])

        # Increase the length of the palindrome from the center
        while (
            with_boundaries[i + palindrome_lengths[i] + 1]
            == with_boundaries[i - (palindrome_lengths[i] + 1)]
        ):
            palindrome_lengths[i] += 1

        # Update current right boundary and current center index
        if i + palindrome_lengths[i] > right_current:
            right_current = i + palindrome_lengths[i]
            center_current = i

        # Keep track of the longest
        if palindrome_lengths[i] > max_len:
            max_len = palindrome_lengths[i]
            max_center = i
    # return from max_center - max_len to max_center + max_len, filtering out sentinel chars
    return "".join(
        c
        for c in with_boundaries[max_center - max_len : max_center + max_len + 1]
        if c not in "@|!"
    )
```

While it does seem to have quadratic complexity O(n^2), having a while loop inside a for loop, it actually is only O(n), as explained on wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know why are you using clas for this. We in python do not write classes if do not use OOP, which you are not

### Intro

I went through middles of would be palindrome substrings *1,
and from that middle went left until substring was no longer palindrome
or end of the string was met

### code

```py
def find_longest_p(s):
    pal_start = 0; pal_end = 1 # indexes of longest
    for half_index in range(0, len(s)*2-1):
        # about 1st range bounds
        # it goes over middles of palindromes
        # which are at some char or between 2 chars
        # that char is s[half_index/2]
        #    where for odd it is s[x.5] meaning between s[x] a& s[x+1]
        
        c = b = -1 # start with value because for else is asking for b,c
        
        for b in range((half_index + half_index % 2) // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
            # starts from first index to the left, goes to 0
            # "a b c d" (str "abcd", disregard spaces)
            #  0123456  (half indexes)
            # for half_index == 4
            #    b goes -> 1 -> 0
            # for half_index == 3
            #    b goes -> 1 -> 0
            
            c = half_index - b # symetric index of b
            if c < len(s) and s[b] == s[c]: # if not, either end of string or no longer palindrome
                continue
            lenght = c - b - 1
            if lenght > pal_end - pal_start:
                pal_start = b + 1
                pal_end = c
            break
        else:
            # out of bounds to the left
            # arithmetic changes a little
            lenght = c - b + 1
            if lenght > pal_end - pal_start:
                pal_start = b
                pal_end = c + 1
    return s[pal_start : pal_end]
```

### complexity

It seems that this has O(n^2)
which is not actually the case, since, in an *average* string, not much of palindromes are found.
meaning the 2nd loop mostly has a single iteration
taking **O(n) time** complexity,
and additional **O(1) space**, defining 3 variables, and some middle products,
or **O(n) space** if you include copying and slicing s (that is inevitable)

### Footnotes

***1** middle of palindrome can be at some index or in between two indexes
therefore, I went through double indexes
middles would be: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, ...
I went:           0,  1,  2,  3,  ...

Comment: This answer doesn't work for strings like "bba", and has O(n^2) worst case time complexity for strings like "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"

Comment: I did say _average_

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can actually solve this problem using dynamically generated regular expressions.

```
# Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62838784/optimize-time-space-complexity-for-solving-palindromes

import re
import time


def longestPalindrome(string, longest_first=True):
    palindrome = None
    order = range(len(string)//2, -1, -1) if longest_first else range(1, len(string)//2+1)
    for n in order:
        # Example: re.sub(r'^.*(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w)?\3\2\1.*$', r'\1\2\3\4\3\2\1', s)
        regex_match = "".join([
            r'^.*',
            r'(\w)' * n,
            r'(\w)?',
            ''.join([ f'\\{i}' for i in range(n,0,-1) ]),
            r'.*$'
        ])
        if re.match(regex_match, string):
            regex_replace = "".join([ f'\\{i}' for i in list(range(1,n+2))+list(range(n,0,-1)) ])
            palindrome    = re.sub(regex_match, regex_replace, string)
            if longest_first:
                return palindrome  # return the first match
        else:
            if not longest_first:
                break  # return the last match

    return palindrome


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for longest_first in [True, False]:
        print(f'\nLongest First = {longest_first}')
        for sentence in [
            "banana",
            "tracecars",
            "detartrated",
            "saippuakivikauppias",
            "this is not the palindrome you are looking for"
        ]:
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            answer     = longestPalindrome(sentence, longest_first)
            time_taken = time.perf_counter() - start_time
            print(f'len({len(sentence):2d}) in {1000*time_taken:6.2f}ms = longestPalindrome({sentence}, {longest_first}) == {answer}')

    assert longestPalindrome("banana")      == "anana"
    assert longestPalindrome("tracecars")   == "racecar"
    assert longestPalindrome("detartrated") == "detartrated"
```

```
Longest First = True
len( 6) in   0.79ms = longestPalindrome(banana, True) == anana
len( 9) in   0.39ms = longestPalindrome(tracecars, True) == racecar
len(11) in   0.41ms = longestPalindrome(detartrated, True) == detartrated
len(19) in   0.59ms = longestPalindrome(saippuakivikauppias, True) == saippuakivikauppias
len(46) in  13.19ms = longestPalindrome(this is not the palindrome you are looking for, True) == oo

Longest First = False
len( 6) in   0.06ms = longestPalindrome(banana, False) == anana
len( 9) in   0.08ms = longestPalindrome(tracecars, False) == racecar
len(11) in   0.19ms = longestPalindrome(detartrated, False) == detartrated
len(19) in   0.46ms = longestPalindrome(saippuakivikauppias, False) == saippuakivikauppias
len(46) in   0.04ms = longestPalindrome(this is not the palindrome you are looking for, False) == oo
```

There are two algorithm options, one that searches for the longest possible palindrome first then shrinks the regex until it finds a match, the other checks if a 2-char palindrome exists first then keeps growing the regexp until it has found the longest match.

**In the longest_first version:**

Best case time complexity, for a true palindrome, is `O(N)` as the regex just needs to loop over the string once to verify.

Worst case time complexity is for a non-palindrome. The main loop will run N/2 times. Regexp time complexity on the first loop will need to read half the string to exclude, then on the second loop check two combinations of positions: `O(N/2)` + `O(2*(N/2-1))`, `O(3*(N/2-2))` and so on. Wolfram Alpha says this is `O(N^3/48 + N^2/8 + N/6)` ~= `(N/3)^3 + (N/3)^2`. So overall time complexity is about `O((N/4)^4)`.

- https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28m+*+%28N%2F2-%28m-1%29%29%29+for+m+%3D+1...N%2F2.

However, even for short sentences, actual execution time is still in the millisecond range, which may be fast enough not to have to worry about it.

**Shortest First**

If you change the assumption to be that most inputs will not be palindromes, then it may be quicker to test if a palindrome of length 2 exists before incrementally expanding to larger substrings. This is a tradeoff between best and worst case time complexity. Non-palindromes can be excluded quickly, but long palindromes will take a bit of extra time.